# How to decrease speed of loading bar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make a custom loading bar animation which lasts 7 seconds. I have created using javascript as following, however it goes faster than I expected. What is the correct way to make it lasts 7 seconds?

```js
function move() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");
  var width = 2;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 1);

  function frame() {
    if (width >= 100) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      width++;
      elem.style.width = width + '%';
      elem.innerHTML = width * 1 + '%';
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#myProgress {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

#myBar {
  width: 10%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  text-align: center;
  /* To center it horizontally (if you want) */
  line-height: 30px;
  /* To center it vertically */
  color: white;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:200px;align:left;text-align:left;border-radius:6px;">
  <div id="myProgress">
    <div id="myBar">1%</div>
  </div>
</div>

<button value="run" onclick="move()">RUN</button>
```

Demo https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zbvzgL

Comment: There's 100 steps in the animation, so if you want it to last 7 seconds make the interval 70ms

Comment: Since 7 seconds is 7000 ms, you start at 1 and want to stop at 100, you need to change the styling 99 times in 7 seconds. So 7000 / 99 = 70.7...... . Or start at 0% and just use 70. So use an interval every 70ms instead of every 1ms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `timeout` time to a greater value, as time in the `setTimeout` function is measured in **ms**, **1ms** is a very small time interval. Try with **10ms** or **100ms** according to the speed you need.

```
setInterval(frame, 100);
```

```js
function move() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");
  var width = 2;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 100);
  function frame() {
    if (width >= 100) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      width++;
      elem.style.width = width + '%';
      elem.innerHTML = width * 1 + '%';
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#myProgress {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
border-radius:6px;
}

#myBar {
  width: 10%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  text-align: center; /* To center it horizontally (if you want) */
  line-height: 30px; /* To center it vertically */
  color: white;
border-radius:6px;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:200px;align:left;text-align:left;border-radius:6px;">
<div id="myProgress">
  <div id="myBar">1%</div>
</div>
</div>

<button value="run" onclick="move()">RUN</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

If showing load percentage is optional, you can use CSS to achieve this operation. CSS animation will always be faster than JS animation.

```js
function move() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");
  elem.innerText = "Loading...";
  elem.classList.add('slow');
  setTimeout(function() { elem.innerText = "Loading Completed"; }, 7000)
}
```

```css
#myProgress {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

#myBar {
  width: 0%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  text-align: center;
  /* To center it horizontally (if you want) */
  line-height: 30px;
  /* To center it vertically */
  color: white;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

#myBar.slow {
  width: 100%;
  transition: 7000ms;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:200px;align:left;text-align:left;border-radius:6px;">
  <div id="myProgress">
    <div id="myBar"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<button value="run" onclick="move()">RUN</button>
```

Comment: Loads very smooth, however the % has gone

Comment: @user198989 That is by design. I have already mentioned in description

Answer (score 1):

You need to change setInterval value, For Example ->

```
var id = setInterval(frame, 15);
```

and also if you want 7 seconds 70 or 60 it's enough for you.

```
var id = setInterval(frame, 60);
```